# MySql function tax (calculate IVA)

Tags: mysql, bash

The problem is i'm writing the function directly from shell(bash)
trying to translate the syntax from some IDE that i don't know !!
The original function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcIVA(@Price money)RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IVA money
  SET @IVA = @Price * 1.16
  RETURN @IVA
END;
```

So changed some syntax to work with `mysql>` prompt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculoIVA(x INT)RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE IVA INT
  SET IVA = x *1.16 
  RETURN IVA 
END;
```

What i'm doing wrong?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SET `IVA` = `x` *1.16 RETURN `IVA` END' at line 1

Comment: where i missed the semicolon? i don't see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine what datatypes you want. `INT` won't work so hot with your 1.16 idea. You lose to rounding to an INT. The below does not use `INT`

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CalculoIVA;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CalculoIVA
(x DECIMAL(12,4))
RETURNS DECIMAL(12,4) 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE IVA DECIMAL(12,4); -- OR FLOAT etc
  SET IVA = x *1.16; 
  RETURN IVA;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;

select CalculoIVA(9.12);
-- 10.5792
```

If you want the datatypes to be `DECIMAL(12,2)` or `FLOAT` just make the necessary changes.

Note: the DELIMITER wrapper is unnecessary for PHPMyAdmin users.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem. I was trying with FLOAT as well , but wasn't working neither. Thanks!

Comment: yw anytime just holler

Comment: Now i can see the missed semicolon within the codeblock inside the Function!!